# Default functions in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a snippet like that, which works:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    state = { counter : 0 }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        counter: this.state.counter+1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {this.state.counter}
        </button>
    )
  }
}
```

Above, the `handleClick` function is an arrow one.
Below, instead I'm trying to use default function (from ES5):

```
 class Button extends React.Component {
    state = { counter : 0 }
  handleClick = function() {
    this.setState({
        counter: this.state.counter+1
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {this.state.counter}
        </button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button/>, mountNode)
```

The problem that the second snippet don't work properly is in function's writing way? Or somewhere else? React js do not handle default functions?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Comment: What do you mean by not working properly? If you are having any errors please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Any error, just does not work - counter state does not react on clicks.

Answer (score 2):

When you write this:

```
class Example {
  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.doStuff(e);
  }
}
```

it's being transpiled by Babel to something like this:

```
var Example = function Example() {
  var _this = this;

  this.handleClick = function (e) {
    return _this.doStuff(e);
  };
};
```

The method `handleClick` has access to the object's instance because the constructor stores the instance in the variable `_this` and the method forms a closure where `_this` is available in its *lexical environment*. It uses `_this` instead of the keyword `this`, because when called by an event listener that doesn't know about the original object, `this` would have the value `window` (or `undefined` if strict mode is enabled).

---

Now, when you use a regular `function` instead of an arrow function, like so:

```
class Test {
  handle = function (e) {
     return this.doStuff(e);
  }
}
```

It's transpiled to something like this instead:

```
var Test = function Test() {
  this.handle = function (e) {
    return this.doStuff(e);
  };
};
```

As you can see, it's now trying to access the instance via the keyword `this`, which won't be the object instance when the method is called from an event listener, so it won't work as expected.

---

If you're a dreamer like me and you like thinking about a world where the "class properties transform" is part of the actual spec and we're all using ES2xxx natively, you can think of the arrow function version as equivalent to the following:

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.handleClick = (e) => {
      this.doStuff(e);
    }
  }
}
```

You can see here that it's creating an arrow function in the constructor, and since arrow functions take their *context* (i.e. the value of `this`) from the surrounding scope, and the scope here is the constructor itself, `this` will have the appropriate value, no matter where the method is called.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, `this` has a different meaning when used in an arrow function. `this` in an `arrow` function refers to the instance of the `class` it is wrapped in where `this` in a usual `function` refers to the instance of the `function` itself and not the `class`. This is termed as **Lexical `this`** in the ES6 specs

Therefore, in your case, the `this.state.counter+1` in the normal `function` will be `undefined`. If you must use `function`,
then I guess you should do this:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  state = { counter : 0 }
  self = this
  handleClick = function() {
    self.setState({
      counter: self.state.counter+1
    })
  }
  ...
}

ReactDOM.render(<Button/>, mountNode)
```

IMO, binding is better though

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind method to your class:

```
onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your ES5 code replace the following

```
onClick={this.handleClick}
```

with

```
onClick={this.handleClick()}
```

Comment: I tried that - "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: This is wrong. You pass a function as a click handler, not a function call. There's an important difference. You're telling React's synthetic event system which function to call when a click event is registered.

Comment: @Adam It was maxing out the call stack because it was calling `handleClick` on every render, and since `handleClick` calls `setState`, it was triggering a new render, creating an infinite loop.